# SSIS: Fill column based on certain string from other column

Tags: ssis

I have a table filled with random text and I want to create a new column, based on certain words in that text column.

For Example, I have following table:

```
ID | text
1  | I like that car
2  | That restaurant is too expensive
3  | We have a cat
4  | I'm sleepy
```

I want to search based on keywords that the text column contains to get this result:

```
ID | text                                     | Category
1  | I like that car                          | Vehicle
2  | That dinner is too expensive             | Food
3  | We have a cat                            | Animals
4  | I'm sleepy                               | Other
```

What I was thinking was to use a derived column with

```
FINDSTRING(text,"car",1) > 0 ? "Vehicle" : FINDSTRING(text,"cat",1) > 0 ? Animals : ...
```

But that doesn't seem like a good idea since I really need to search for 20 keyword within the text column. I tried to do it with multiple derived columns after each other, but then they just override the new column over and over.
Any other suggestions or ways to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your Keywords and their Categories in a table, and populate the Category column in the SQL query in your Source Component.

Comment: May want to apply a SELECT TOP 1 in your sql statement for the category in case the text is "Fed cat dinner".  Here you have two categories, one for Animals and the other for Food.  If only one category per ID is allowed, then the SELECT TOP 1 will just get the first instance.